# Simple Code Addition Breaks Google Maps Display

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here is google's hello world code for v3:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#HelloWorld

this loads and displays the map just fine. However, once I add any code within the script tags, the map no longer displays. For example
if I just declare a class immediately after initialize(), the map no longer displays.

Here is an example:

http://hollaballoon.com/test/test.html

Please download the source and try for yourself. How can this be solved?

Comment: Can you add an example of the code with your additions?

Comment: Yes I just uploaded a link to the edited code.

Comment: If you use chrome developer tools or Firebug with Firefox, it can easily spot this kind of problem right away. As Felix Yan said, you declared a function using var and that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to think about using a javascript debugger to help you develop. The code you added after the google maps stuff has some syntax problems. Firefox has a great add-on called Firebug, and Chrome/Safari both have built in debuggers.

Having said that, you might try changing your code to this instead:

```
//The place class
var Place = function(type, address){
    this.type = type;
    this.address = address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, problem is, Functions(that's your "class") should be defined using `function` keyword, not `var`. And that breaks everything.

Comment: I am ashamed of my stupidity. I am just starting out with js. Would you be so kind as to explain why my onclick method is not being triggered? (I edited the code at http://hollaballoon.com/test/test.html

Comment: You should do this like `onClick="javascript: function();"`, don't forget the `javascript:` part :)

Comment: I did exactly as you said, Felix, and still I am getting an error (using the very helpful chrome developer tools people recommended)

Comment: That's because `createEvent` is reversed and should not be used, try to change your func's name :)

Comment: Wow thanks! So explain that to me again why I cannot use createEvent as a function name? It is reversed?

Comment: Ah so I basically attempted to override the method. Thank you for all of your help, Felix :)